# Why do I assign data directly to MutableState variable?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I was told that `MutableState` just like `MutableLiveData` in Kotlin, and `MutableStat`e fit Compose, MutableLiveData`enter code here` fit XML layout.

In Code A, I need to assign data to `bb.value,` but why do I assign directly to `aa` ?

**Code A**

```
private var aa by mutableStateOf(-1)

private var bb= MutableLiveData<Int>(-1)  

fun onEditDone() {
    aa = 2
    bb.value = 2
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of Kotlin's delegation feature where you delegate values using `by` keyword.

Simple implementation for remember and mutableState, to display how it works when you build something similar to that, is as

```
// Delegation Functions for setting and getting value
operator fun <T> State<T>.getValue(thisObj: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): T = value

operator fun <T> MutableState<T>.setValue(thisObj: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) {
    this.value = value
}

/*
 *  State
 */
interface State<out T> {
    val value: T
}
interface MutableState<T> : State<T> {
    override var value: T
}

class MutableStateImpl<T>(value: T) : MutableState<T> {
    override var value: T = value
}

fun <T> mutableStateOf(value: T): MutableState<T> = MutableStateImpl(value)

/*
 *  Remember
 */

inline fun <T> remember(calculation: () -> T): T {
    return calculation()
}
```

And you can use it as

```
fun main() {

    val isSelected: MutableState<Boolean> = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
    isSelected.value = false

    var selected by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    selected = false
}
```