# Why Compose remembers a state of an object rather than the object itself?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

I learned that Compose remembers a state in a way such as:

```
var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
```

So in this case, it remembers a `MutableState` of a `String`.  My question is why it wants to remember a thing called "MutableState" rather than just the String itself, and why it requires an extra layer?

Answer (score 2):

I know its late, but here's what I understand with `remember`.

I have a simple Todo app where a list of todos are hoisted in a `viewwmodel`using a `SnapshotStatelist`, this list is rendered by a `LazyColumn` where each todo `model` has its own `remembered` `state` where I do some pretty basic UI functionality (e.g card elevation, visibility of some icons). Any changes I make to a todo should propagate back up to the `mutableStateList` (e.g deleting a todo), `SnapshotStateList` will then notify the `LazyColumn` to perform a `recomposition`, however when I `edit` a Todo (e.g, modifying the title), I also have to update the `item` `composable` that holds this todo(some UI changes), then I got stuck up as I can't figure out why the `item` `composable` is not `recomposing` even if I was able to verify that the `SnapShotStateList` item is modified by using the code below

```
val todoList = viewModel.todos
val snapshot = Snapshot.takeMutableSnapshot()
snapshot.enter {
    for (todo in todoList) {
        Log.e("TodoModel", todo.title)
    }
}
```

Code that modifies the list

```
val index = todos.indexOfFirst { it.id == modifiedModel.id }
todos[index] = todos[index].copy(//..some properties to be copied)
```

I verified that any **modification** I make on a todo reflects back to its host list, but the `item` `composable` that renders a todo item doesn't trigger a `re-composition`. I kept reading some posts and carefully thinking object references and trying to understand my code based on this object reference thought, I thought that there must be something that holds the previous state of the `item` and the changes is not applied to the `remember`, until I found that you can supply a `key` to a `remember` where it will be the thing that will decide if  `remember` needs to re-calculate. Now I found out that `remember` only remembers a state (by state I dont mean compose state, but state in general) on **initial** `composition`, it will keep that initial structure/state for as long as the entire composable it is part of is still running, in this case all the way up to the parent `composable` (i.e my DashboardScreen), what made my `remember` **re-calculate** is I supplied the key with the todo object itself

```
val itemState: ItemCardState = remember(key1 = todoModel) {
    ItemCardState(todoModel = todoModel)
}
```

This way, when a change happens to the `SnapShotStateList`, an `item`'s `remember` will see the same object reference (data class) but with changes applied to it. `remember` caches the initial state and will hold it forever unless you supply a key that you think might change and will let `remember` re-calculate a new **initial** state to be remembered, in my case I supplied the key as the todo object itself and when `remember` sees the same object reference but with a different value, it will `re-calculate`.

Having this understanding now, I can't imagine a way when there is no layer that will hold an object (`remember`) and prevent unnecessary re-composition when the state of an object changes.

Just sharing what I learned, also open for discussion that I may have said in a wrongful way.

Answer (score 1):

remember is used for storing objects to have it when a recomposition happens. Mutable state is used for triggering recomopsition, you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69961175/5457853) for more details.

by is [delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69205446/5457853) that is a feature of Kotlin which translates the code

```
var text = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
text.value = "newString"
```

you basically store a trigger and value inside a remember. when you change `MutableState`.value new recomposition occurs and in this new recomposition you get the latest value of MutableState.

There are also usecases of remember without needing `MutableState` like a `Paint` or **custom object** when something else triggers the recomposition like canvas touch position for instance.

you remember object since you won't instantiate it.

```
val paint = remember {Paint()}
var offset by remember {mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero)
```

then when offset changes with user touching screen you trigger recomposition but since and you don't need to instantiate Paint object again.

`remember` only and `remember` with `MutableState` has different usecases.

Answer (score 1):

Mutable state is needed for two reasons:

1. Saving mutable state between recompositions. `remember` is gonna save result of lambda calculation, but if you change a variable later - `remember` cannot save and track it. The solution is to have a state holder - an object that's created by `mutableStateOf`, saved by `remember`, will always be the same, but you can mutate it properties, in this case `value` (which is hidden when you're using delegation with `by`).
2. Triggering recomposition. If you just create a class, save it with `remember` and update a property, Compose won't know that it was changed, and that view update it needed - that's why a special Compose State was created, which notifies a view that it needs to be recomposed.

You can continue deepening your knowledge with state in Compose [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state) and [Thinking in Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model).